# Is there a way that I could execute files remotely with files containing include?

Tags: bash, ssh, remote

I am trying to execute ssh command to execute files remotely.

```
ssh root@abc 'bash -s ' < filename.sh
```

But it won't work because `filename.sh` has a `.`/`source` command that references another file.

Example :

`filename.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'hello'

. parameter.sh

echo 'Hello'
```

How do I run this `filename.sh` file remotely? Without transferring `parameter.sh`?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can't but in this instance, you could do:

```
{
  cat parameter.sh
  grep -xvF '. parameter.sh' filename.sh
} | ssh host bash -s
```

That is pass the content of both files as input to the remote `bash` and remove the `.` command which is then no longer needed.